# Modifying/Filtering yytext before calling yymore()

Tags: flex-lexer

Assume that I have the following:

pattern  { /* Filter/process here then call */ yymore(); }

What I would like to do is filter/process some things in yytext before calling yymore(). yytext is never going to grow in length only possibly get shorter by the processing. This would require being able to shorten yytext. As a starting point, I tried to see if there is an easy way to e.g. delete the last character of yytext, but doing something naive like

yytext[yyleng-1] = '\0'; yyleng--;

won't work. yymore() seems to append stuff after the NIL character, which would indicate that there is some pointer inside the code generated by flex that points to the current end of yytext. Is there some idiomatic way of doing this without having to write a more complicated set of rules?

Things like yyless puts things back in the input stream which is not what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that in the C version of 'flex', as `yytext` points directly into the input buffer. It isn't a copy. If you modify the input buffer you will screw things up royally.  *flex* takes extreme care to process each character once and only once, and it doesn't do any extra buffering of its own beyond whatever the source you provide to it does. I believe it temporarily puts a NUL into the buffer while executing an action, and takes it out again when the action returns, for which purpose it must therefore have a pointer to where the NUL was.

I would move that processing into the grammar at the appropriate points, where you must already be taking a copy of `yytext.`

Comment: Is there some good source on how flex internally does its buffer management or do I just need to read the source of what it generates? I was assuming that flex will read in a lot of stuff at once from files for efficiency, so it would have an input buffer that contains more material than what has been read into yytext. In this case yytext could not point into that buffer, since it's a nil terminated string, so yytext[yyleng] can't contain both the next character to read from the input stream as well as nil.

Comment: I learned all this from reading the source code thoroughly, many *(many)* years ago while I was contributing the 8-bit code, and via some mail exchanges with Vern Paxson in the process. The whole motivation for *flex* was that Vern was working on 'the fastest data acquisition programs in the world', and nothing - *nothing* - was allowed to get in the way. Years later he wouldn't even admit a virtual function into the C++ version.

Comment: @EdvardFagerholm: yytext[yyleng] cannot *simultaneously* hold both a NUL and the next character (unless of course the next character is NUL), but EJP's answer is 100% correct: flex saves the next character, overwrites a 0, executes the action, and then restores the input buffer. The usual strategy to achieve what you are looking for is to incrementally copy the filtered text values into an accumulator; GNU software typically uses an obstack for that purpose, which minimizes reallocation copying. (http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Obstacks.html)

Comment: Thanks guys. This is precisely what I wanted to know and I'll just read the source. I was trying avoid using an external buffer as an accumulator to preserve memory and copying.